# Как связать с одним полем таблицы несколько полей другой таблицы?

Tags: sql, yii2

Всем привет. У меня есть две таблицы 'items' и 'options'. У одного 'item' может быть несколько параметров 'options', как на картинке [image: картинке]

Возможно ли построить такие связи между двумя таблицами?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для каждого Item может быть только один Options с выбранным Id_items

Ограничение первичного ключа в ItemsOptions

[image: Пример]